# How to use eloquent "With" query within a join query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to use eloquent's with query within a join query to attach the relationships of the table I am joining with however I am faced with the error **"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::with()"**

Hence, how can I use the different with query to attach the relationship data that I need to my target table that I am joining with? (Manual tickets table)

```
$manual_tickets = ManualTicketLog::select('*')
            ->where('manual_ticket_logs.user_id','=',$user->id)
            ->where(function ($checkStatus) {
                $checkStatus->where('manual_ticket_logs.status','=','Created')
                    ->orWhere('manual_ticket_logs.status','=','Started');
            })
            ->whereIn('manual_ticket_logs.id', function($q){
                $q->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) FROM manual_ticket_logs WHERE (manual_ticket_logs.status != "ClockedOutUser" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "ClockedOutSupervisor" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "AssignByLocation" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "Queued") GROUP BY manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id'));  
            })
            ->join('manual_tickets', function ($join) {
                $join->on('manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id', '=', 'manual_tickets.id')
                ->where('manual_tickets.hidden','=',null)
                ->with('prior_rerouted_ticket');
            })
            ->select('manual_tickets.*', 'manual_ticket_logs.id as manual_ticket_logs_id')
            ->get();
```

***Portion of code that results in error***

```
->with('prior_rerouted_ticket');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$manual_tickets = ManualTicketLog::select('*')
            ->where('manual_ticket_logs.user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->where(function ($checkStatus) {
                $checkStatus->where('manual_ticket_logs.status', '=', 'Created')
                    ->orWhere('manual_ticket_logs.status', '=', 'Started');
            })
            ->whereIn('manual_ticket_logs.id', function ($q) {
                $q->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) FROM manual_ticket_logs WHERE (manual_ticket_logs.status != "ClockedOutUser" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "ClockedOutSupervisor" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "AssignByLocation" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "Queued") GROUP BY manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id'));
            })
            ->join('manual_tickets', function ($join) {
                $join->on('manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id', '=', 'manual_tickets.id')
                    ->where('manual_tickets.hidden', '=', null);
            })
            ->with('manual_tickets.prior_rerouted_ticket')
            ->select('manual_tickets.*', 'manual_ticket_logs.id as manual_ticket_logs_id')
            ->get();
```

Move relations from join.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by restructuring the query. Instead of querying from the  manual ticket logs table and then joining it to the manual tickets table whilst trying to find a way to attach the relationship to the manual tickets table, I queried from the manual tickets table first and attached it's relationship before joining it to the manual ticket logs table

```
    $manual_tickets = ManualTicket::select('*')
            ->where('manual_tickets.hidden','=',null)
            ->where('manual_tickets.user_id','=',$user->id)
            ->join('manual_ticket_logs', function ($join) use($user) {
                $join->on('manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id', '=', 'manual_tickets.id')
                ->where('manual_ticket_logs.user_id','=',$user->id)
                ->where(function ($checkStatus) {
                    $checkStatus->where('manual_ticket_logs.status','=','Created')
                        ->orWhere('manual_ticket_logs.status','=','Started');
                })
                ->whereIn('manual_ticket_logs.id', function($q){
                    $q->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) FROM manual_ticket_logs WHERE (manual_ticket_logs.status != "ClockedOutUser" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "ClockedOutSupervisor" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "AssignByLocation" and manual_ticket_logs.status != "Queued") GROUP BY manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id'));  
                });
            })
            ->with('manual_tickets.prior_rerouted_ticket')
            ->select('manual_tickets.*', 'manual_ticket_logs.id as manual_ticket_logs_id')
            ->get();
```